# Indian Date and time in php

Tags: php, date

Guys I am trying to get correct Indian time and date in PHP

I have tried this code:

```
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$date1 =  date("H:i a");

if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
}

echo $date;
echo $date1;
```

But I am not getting correct time. I am getting time which is `4.30` Hours late. Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the timezone declaration first before using any date function:

```
// set the timezone first
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
}

// then use the date functions, not the other way around
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$date1 =  date("H:i a");

echo $date . '<br/>';
echo $date1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The cleaner option is

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimezone("Asia/Kolkata"));
echo $date->format('d/m/y').'<br/>';
echo $date->format('H:i a');
```

This way, you wouldn't alter global state, so other pieces of the code can still use other timezones

Comment: Best answer :).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo "The date is " .date("d/m/y"); 
echo "<br/>";
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation alongside your code. Code only answers are frowned upon in the community guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`
and 
`$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
what ever format you like!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// set the timezone first
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
}

// then use the date functions, not the other way around
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$date1 =  date("H:i a");

echo $date . '<br/>';
echo $date1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**Get Indian time and date now**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo "The date is " .date("d/m/y"); 
echo "<br/>";
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer replicates some others. While answering, be sure to add some value and not just repurposing existing content. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

you should try

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

echo "Current Data & time-->".$date;

Comment: How does your answer differ from previous ones?